# C++ doubling index vector of unique ordered relationships

Tags: vector, hashmap, mapping, c++14, std

I'm looking for an std style container, i.e. with iterators and such with a
structure along the lines of:

```
template <hashable T, hasable U> class relationships {
    relation(std::[vector or list]<std::pair<T,U>> list);
    const std::pair<T,U>& operator [](const T index);
    const std::pair<T,U>& operator [](const U index);
}
```

This is for a two way mapping, into a order list of pairs, every value of both T and U are unique, and both are hashable, and the pairs of related T and U have a specific ordering to them, that should be reproduce by the following loop

```
for (auto it : relationships) {
    // do something with it
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
for (auto it : list) {
    // do something with it
}
```

I also want efficient lookup i.e. operator [], should be equivalent to an std::unorderd_map for both types.

Finally I'm look for solutions based around the Standard Library using C++14 and DO NOT WANT TO USE BOOST.

I seen how to implement a Hash map previously using binary search trees, however I looking for insight in how to efficiently maintain the structure for two indexes plus ordered elements, or existing solutions if one exists:

my current idea is something using nodes along the line of

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct node {
    std::pair<T, U> value; // actual value
    // hashs for sorting binary trees
    size_t hashT;
    size_t hashU;
    // linked list for ordering
    node * prevL;
    node * nextL;
    // binary search tree for type T lookup
    node * parentT;
    node * prevT;
    node * nextT;
    // binary search tree for type U lookup
    node * parentU;
    node * prevU;
    node * nextU;
}
```

However that seams inefficient

my other idea is to store a vector or values, which has order, and then two sorted index vectors of `std::pair<size_t, size_t>` with first being the hash, and second the index, however how should I deal with performing a binary search on the index vector and handle hash collisions. I believe this solution would be more memory efficient and similar speed, but not sure on all the implementation details.

EDIT: I don't need fast insertions, just lookup and iteration, the mapping is would be generated once and then used to find relationships.

Comment: If you want performance, what do you want to be fast: iteration, search or insertion ? Basically most of the time you would base your new data structure around a vector, or, on rare cases, around a hashmap. Vector are fast iterating, fast inserting and fast searching if they are constructed for good so you can sort them. Hashmap are faster seaching if you keep inserting elements in between searches.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding performance it all depends on the algorithm and the type of T and U  you are trying to use . If you build your data and then do not change it, a simple solution would be the following:

1. Use a `vector<pair<T,U>>` for constructing your data
2. duplicate this vector
3. sort one vector according to T, one according to U
4. use binary search for fast lookup, either in the first vector if looking by T, or in the second if looking by U
5. hide all this behind a construct/sort/access interface. You might not want to use `operator[]` since you are expected to look into your data structure only once sorted

Of course the solution is not perfect in the sense that you are copying data. However, remember that you will have no extra hidden allocation as you would with a hashmap. For example, for T = U = int, I would think that there will be no more memory in use than a `std::unordered_map`, since each node needs to store a pointer.